# Llenar un numero aleatorio con zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy generando números aleatorios con la siguiente variable:

```
numeroAleatorio = randint(1,9999)
```

El problema que se me presenta es que el numero debe ser de 4 dígitos. He probado a usar `zfill` de la siguiente manera:

```
print(string.format(numeroAleatorio.zfill(4)))
```

Ejemplo de 5 outputs correctos:

```
0012
9820
0002
1050
0150
```

¿Cómo se podría obtener siempre un numero de 4 dígitos?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema de usar zfill?¿Cuando dices "int de 4 dígitos" te refieres a que tiene que ser entre 1000 y 9999?

Comment: Si te fijas en los ejemplos que he añadido verás el rango al que me refiero, `0001-9999`.

Comment: *¿Cómo se podría obtener siempre un int de 4 dígitos?* Los ceros a la izquierda no tienen valor matemático. Si le pones ceros, dejará de ser un `int` para ser un `string`. No puedes ponerle ceros a la izquierda a un `int` porque matemáticamente es incorrecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con información extraida de:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733454/best-way-to-format-integer-as-string-with-leading-zeros
Con respuesta a tu pregunta:

> ¿Cómo se podría obtener siempre un `int` de 4 dígitos?

No se puede. No si lo que quieres es que el `int` vaya de 1 a 9999.
Si quieres ceros a la izquierda, debe ser necesariamente otro tipo de dato que admita ese formato. `int` no está pensado para ello, `string` sí.

Este código debería producir el resultado que buscas, aunque debes tener en cuenta que el resultado es un `string` y no un `int` si quieres hacer más cosas con ese resultado después.

```
import random

numeroAleatorio = random.randint(1,9999)
numeroAleatorio_string = str(numeroAleatorio)
numeroAleatorioConCeros = numeroAleatorio_string.zfill(4)
print (numeroAleatorioConCeros)
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y la explicación, es lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

Es super, super simple:

```
numeroAleatorio = randint(1000, 9999)
```

Con esto los valores saldran entre 1000 y 9999, todos con cuatro digitos.

Ojo: 0001 no es un entero en Python, produce un error:

> SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not
> permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Lo único válido que empieza con cero son los valores octales, que deben tener un "0o" al comienzo:

```
In[64]: 0o7 + 0o2
Out[64]: 9
```

**Demo**

```
from random import randint


for i in range(10):
    numeroAleatorio = randint(1000, 9999)
    print(numeroAleatorio)
```

produce:

```
5596
2478
3373
1646
7118
8495
8918
2045
7830
6497

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Según el OP, el rango tiene que ser `0001-9999`, no `1000-9999`

Comment: @Esel. Según Python, 0001 no es un entero válido.

Comment: Claro, por eso puse como comentario al OP en su pregunta que no se podía, que necesitaba un string sí o sí